# She wants to 'poop' -is that okay if used for humans?

Tags: word-request

I know the *verb* 'poop' but then not sure whether it's used for humans. More often than not, I've come across this verb when we talk about pets.

But here, I'm searching for a **verb** in both ways - formal and informal. And yes, I want to learn **how native speakers tell this-**

> Yes, she wants to ____________

Please note that I am aware of the usage "She wants to go to loo/toilet" but then it does not solve my purpose. Loo/Toilet is just a place but I want to specifically ask/tell that a kid wants to defecate.

### Practical problem

At times it happens with me too!

I was at some small place near Port Hope (Canada), and I asked for a *washroom* thinking that it's a general term. A guy there showed me the place and I went.

### I saw this-

[image: Urinals]

### And there was NO ...

[image: commodes]

Luckily, I wanted to go No 1. But then it triggered ***this*** question in my mind! What if I want to make sure to the listener that I am asking for a commode and not urinals.

Comment: Warning: All but one answer so far is _highly_ Americentric. In actual English nobody says "poop"!

Comment: American English *is* actual English.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I say poop. It's a funny word. It's just that typically people don't say poop because it sounds: childish, lacking in class, and/or undignified. Poop :)

Comment: If you're going to unnecessarily use images instead of words in your post, *please* at least give the images a description and don't leave the default "add image description here". Your question makes no sense at all to anyone using a screen reader.

Comment: The question asks for a formal verb to talk about defecating. My experience (in the US) is that most people would simply not talk about it in a formal setting and would rather use euphemisms instead. There is somewhat of a taboo around feces in formal settings. Informal settings would be okay with `poop`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - it would certainly be understood, and I've heard it used (albeit rarely).

Comment: @JonStory: Yes, it would be understood.

Comment: @OwenJohnson In the US, there is no need for specificity because virtually every restroom comes "fully equipped." To find a restroom with urinals but no toilet is *extremely* rare in the US.

Answer (score 17):

> Please note that I am aware of the usage "She wants to go to loo/toilet" but then it does not solve my purpose. Loo/Toilet is just a place but I want to specifically ask/tell that a kid wants to defecate.

In British English, "Go to the loo/toilet" doesn't just mean going to the room or the piece of furniture: it means using said piece of furniture. "Poop" is American; the British equivalent is "poo" but that's something you'd normally only say to a child.

For adults, in most situations, you don't need to say *why* somebody is going to the toilet: that's seen as private and people don't talk about it. You might excuse yourself from the room by saying that you're going to the toilet but the people you're talking to don't need or want to know exactly what you plan to do there. Saying where you're going serves more to inform them that you'll be back soon. As such, if adults do talk to each other about defecation, it's usually in either euphemistic ("doing a number two"), coarse ("taking a dump") or offensive ("going for a shit") terms. The main exception to this would be your doctor, who's likely to use terms like "defecate", "bowel movements" or "passing solids".

> I was at some small place near Port Hope (Canada), and I asked for a washroom thinking that it's a general term. A guy there showed me the place and I went. I saw [urinals] but no [stalls].

Yes, washroom/restroom/bathroom (North America) or toilets/loos/bathroom (UK) is the general term. I've *never* seen a men's toilets with only urinals, anywhere I've been (UK, Europe, North America). It seems most likely that you missed the stalls/cubicles: perhaps they were behind a door that you mistook for a storage cupboard or something.  In my experience, anywhere that has space has both urinals and stalls; anywhere that doesn't have space for both just has an ordinary toilet.

Comment: The question arises as in some places, if you just ask for a loo/toilet, what you have (say for men) is just urinating and not commode. It's for this reason, we need to mention that no, I'm not going for No.1 but No.2!

Comment: @MaulikV Answer edited. I've never come across anywhere where the men's toilets had only urinals.

Comment: @MaulikV The situation you were in almost never happens, though. Whoever made the decision to build a bathroom with only urinals is a complete idiot in every sense of the word; he went through all the trouble have the plumbing routed only to not allow customers to relieve themselves fully. Most places either have both or only commodes.

Comment: Often male friends will explain exactly what they need to do as a shock factor type thing ("fancy a pint? I just need to go for a shit first, and then violently so after having ten"), but nobody would ever mention anything scatalogical when talking to other people.

Comment: You only really find "washroom" in Canada. Most Americans would probably understand what you meant, but very few would ever call it that on their own.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, "to poop" is used for humans.  However, I think it sounds a little strange to say, "Yes, she wants to _____."  I would say, "Yes, she needs to poop."  "To poop" is the way that thought is expressed most of the time.

Other ways to say it:

> "Yes, she needs to defecate." *medical/clinical*
> "Yes, she needs to have a bowel movement." *discreet and medical/clinical*
> "Yes, she needs to go number two." *discreet and informal*
>
> "Yes, she needs to take a shit." *vulgar ("shit" is a curse word)*
> "Yes, she needs to take a dump." *vulgar*
> "Yes, she needs to drop the kids off at the pool." *a euphemism - Someone might say this is they were trying to be funny but it's not widely common so you might find some people don't know what you mean.)*

Comment: <andy rooney voice>Why do they call it "taking" a dump, you don't actual take it anywhere, you leave it.

Comment: True...out of all, I think 'poo/p' sounds okay but wasn't sure whether to use it for humans

Comment: "She needs to go #2" is not only discreet but discrete.

Comment: Reminds me of a great xkcd, "reverse euphemisms": http://xkcd.com/168/

Comment: +1 for: "Yes, she needs to drop the kids off at the pool." :)

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the culture, but this would be fine in America (if it's a child, and you specifically have to say it). If you want to be even more discreet, you can also say

> it's a number 2.

Comment: Does that imply number 1 = to pee, number 3 = to vomit, or the like?

Comment: Yes, #1 is the parallel slang for urinating, but #3 is not universally recognized; I've only ever seen it used as a joke, often an off-color one.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say #3

Comment: There are 10 types of people, those that understand binary and those that don't: 01 is pee. 10 is poop. 11 is both.

Comment: Also, in my experience, using the #1 and #2 euphemisms is only for or around young children, and it is specifically for people. A dog, for example, poops instead of "going #2". That may be a regional or cultural difference however.

Comment: I have this idea for a cartoon:  an obviously alien child (i.e. from outer-space) is tugging on one of it's mother's arm-like appendages, and the caption says: "I've have to go #3 !"

Comment: What if it's an adult and not a kid?

Comment: I heard #2 used (I guess in the context of a joke) the other day, without children present. So it's possible, but definitely jocular.

Answer (score 11):

> But here, I'm searching for a verb in both ways - formal and informal.
>   And yes, I want to learn how native speakers tell this-

Informal:  The kindergartner told the teacher that he really needed *to poop*.

The pediatrician asked the young child if everything was OK when he *went poop* (or pooped).

Ron opened the door to find Harry either pooping or working on an *expulso* curse, he was not sure which.

Formal (medical contexts):  The doctor asked if the patient's *bowel movements* had been normal.

The professor told the med students always to inquire if a patient was having any difficulty digesting or defecating.

Comment: "went poop" is very much an americanism; it sounds very wrong to my (British) ear.

Comment: @lmm It's only really said by young kids here.

Comment: When he `went poop`? Dear god, this is not English.

Comment: @Matt Fletcher:  And yet God understands it as though it were.

Comment: @MattFletcher Yes it is. Perhaps it isn't British English, but it's definitely English (albeit extremely informal, and childlike).

Comment: Yes, but that's because children are idiots. Probably not the best examples to use for an English learning site...

Comment: @Matt Fletcher: I believe the OP is in the medical profession; he may need to communicate with young children about this subject.

Answer (score 10):

(I'd have added this as a comment only that requires 50 points.)
To a native British English speaker, "poop" sounds American.  We'd say "poo".

Comment: perhaps best explained by Phil Jupitus (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3pABgbjF24#t=156)

Comment: (Having just finished watching that show, the language gets kinda NSFW a few minutes further in.)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield at what point is watching NMTB safe for work? :P

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly valid and would be understood, however it's generally not used for adults. In other words you would use it for children, but it's highly unlikely it would be used for teenagers or anyone older than that.

Most cultures have regional and class slang with varying degrees of potential offensiveness that would also be used for this so "native" speaking is going to vary a lot based on where you are and the people you are talking to.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, it's very common for young children to say they have to "poop", or "go potty". In fact, it's practically expected. Some people are more uptight and insist on teaching their children to say they have to "go to (use) the bathroom" or some such. Maybe around 10 years-of-age or so does it get kind of weird to say you have to "poop", with any seriousness, anyway. If you're not living in the US, then yes, you'll want to confer with some British subjects or what have you.

Comment: Is "go potty" used by small children and "to poop" a little bit older ones"? Or they are pretty much the same age-wise?

Comment: I think your first question might in fact be the case...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "she needs to poop" is fine, in any context.

But you asked about "she wants to poop".  That sounds very odd to my ears.  I don't think anybody ever really **wants** to poop, it's just one of those things we all have to do from time to time.

Comment: You're right that it's unusual, but there have definitely been occasions where I, as at least a  semi-reasonable adult, have *wanted* to poop. I'll leave the context to your imagination.

Comment: I disagree, I often want to. I make a whole ceremony of it and everything. Candles, violin music, Enya- the whole shebang.

Comment: Just so long as you don't hire a string quartet.

Answer (score -2):

I would not use "poop" at all. What about coining up something that has *"gas"* in it? Yeah, right, I *AM* thinking of that Simpsons episode at the *"Itchy & Scratchy [theme] park"* :-) Remember the "Searing Gas Pain Land"? Yes "gas" in this context *does* stand for "flatulence"! You will know that once you saw that Itchy feeds Scratchy (or vice-versa, can't remember) with *jalapeno pepper*, so that a "tornado" is building up inside him in no time. (P.S. This is a *language-related* SE site, so let me add this bit: in the German translation this was (horribly, even most *officially*) translated into *"Brennendes Benzin-Schmerz-Land"*, with "gas" being misinterpreted as "gasoline" (excuse me Sir or Ma'am, "petrol" for our British readers, indeed).

Comment: "Hello, can I help you?", "Excuse me, yes- I wish to use the lavatory.", "Ah, I see, and what is the exact reason for wishing so?", "Well, you see, I have searing gas that resembles a jalapeño tornado.", "Of course, right this way sir.", etc etc...

Comment: So what, why not? It's at least *creative*, and not *offensive* at all. It *talks* around the problem. Similarly to us IT guys, who always have to *work* around a problem. ;)

Comment: We're more likely to have a _bash_ at if nothing else :P Your answer resembles the ramblings of a mad man but it made me smile at least! :D

Comment: We IT guys are *ALL* mad as a hatter. (Well, roughly 99.5%). Don't say you didn't know? BTW, be glad I wasn't trying to construct anything from Star Trek or so...(in Klingon?!) Or South Park? Geez, gimme a break...